# presentModalViewController does not call any methods

Tags: iphone

In presentModalViewController does not call any methods after login the Facebook using SSO.

```
SignInViewController *signView=[[SignInViewController alloc]init];
signView.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:signView animated:YES];
[signView release];
- (void)cancelAction
{
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The cancelAction method is calling but not dismissed..

Please help me.

Comment: Where you are calling cancelAction?

Answer (score -1):

```
SignInViewController *signView=[[SignInViewController alloc]init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:signView];

[signView release];

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

[navigationController release];

-(void)cancelAction
{

      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

try implementing this...

hope this will work for you..